# Rabbitmq unacked message snarkjs

Tags: rabbitmq, zk-snark

I'm sorry if my question is a little vague but I have this RabbitMQ service and a consumer that executes snarkjs code; Consumer code works fine locally. However, message gets Unacked on staging (heroku).

I'm sure that it's the prover code that runs correctly locally but fails to run on cloud. Any idea why this could have happened?